# How to turn on the audit logging with wsadmin script?

Tags: admin, websphere-8, wsadmin

I would like to turn on the audit logging with a wsadmin script. I was able to create the audit notification like this:

*AdminTask.createAuditNotification('[-notificationName Log_Notification -sendEmail false -emailList  -logToSystemOut true ]')*

But I can't create the auditnotification monitor, becasuse it needs to have the notificationRef:

*AdminTask.createAuditNotificationMonitor('[-monitorName AuditMonitor -notificationRef WSNotification_1428567470299 -enable true ]')*

and if I want to get that ref *(AdminTask.getAuditNotificationRef())* to put it in a variable, then it needs to have the monitor configured first (according to the IBM documentation). If I do not configure the notification monitor first, then the getAuditNotificationRef will return with null value. But if I want to configure the monitor, I need the notificationRef :(.

Kind of confusing stuff for me...could anyone help me with this issue?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked in the knowledgecenter?
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/txml_7auditnotify.html?lang=en

This shows the following example:

AdminTask.createAuditNotification('-notificationName defaultEmailNotification 
-logToSystemOut true -sendEmail true -emailList administrator@mycompany.com(smtp-server.mycompany.com) 
-emailFormat HTML')

AdminTask.createAuditNotificationMonitor('-notificationName defaultEmailNotification 
-logToSystemOut true -sendEmail true -emailList administrator@mycompany.com(smtp-server.mycompany.com) 
-emailFormat HTML')

AdminConfig.save()

As you can see, there is no -notificationRef needed.

Regards, 
Gary